Avoid a path / jar in MANIFEST.MF from being used so that Checkmarkxone does not trigger a scan alert
I am new to Java. I have been handed down some 8 year old code and now we have started using CheckmarkxOne and its triggerring a scan alert on Package Path : org.dom4j:dom4j@2.0.3 and says the latest version is 2.1.3.redhat-00001. File path target/lib/logback-classic-1.5.8/META-INF/maven/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/pom.xml. Need to get this alert to be nullified.
Also have another one org.slf4j:slf4j-ext 1.7.25, CheckMarkx1 says 1.7.25 Your Version(Mar 16, 2017) 2.0.16 Newest version(Aug 10, 2024). Package Path : org.slf4j:slf4j-ext @ 1.7.25. I have made modifications in my pom.xml , but it still flags this error.
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.3.0


CVE-2023-45960 may be a false positive; contact your vendor.

OK, Thank you,  I have another one org.slf4j:slf4j-ext 1.7.25, Cx! says 1.7.25
Your Version(Mar 16, 2017)
2.0.16
Newest version(Aug 10, 2024).  Package Path :
org.slf4j:slf4j-ext @ 1.7.25. I have made modifications in my pom.xml , but it still flags this error.  Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.3.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17

You may be running afoul of CVE-2021-44228. In any case, please [edit] this question to reflect your progress.

@trashgod, My Cyber team (Associate CyberSec person) says that CVE-2023-45960  is not the correct one, I should be looking at NVD - CVE-2020-10683. Not sure what to do now.

CVE-2020-10683 "has been modified since it was last analyzed by the NVD." You and your team need to asses the impact on your usage.

I don't know the exact structure of your JAR-file, but you could try to extract it (it's a renamed ZIP-file), and rebuild it with the Manifest you need.

Also: to check available versions of maven artifacts, you could use [mvnrepository.com] - it lists versions, dependencies, vulnerabilities, etc. (But it is not a maven repository as the name would suggest)
